# How to draw a box/border around plots arranged side by side using grid.arrange in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, border, gridextra

I have created two plots using ggplot as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
g1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) + geom_point()
g2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Width, Petal.Length)) + geom_point()
grid.arrange(g1, g2, ncol=2)
```

I would like to draw a border/box around the two side by side plots produced by grid.arrange...I think it is something to do with using grid.border, but am not sure of how exactly to do so. Will appreciate any help?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might have been downvoted because it is usually a good idea to post a question with a complete [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) example and the full code that can be run via copy-paste.

Comment: Apologize...first time posting.Thanks for editing

Answer (score 3):

Using an example from the ggplot help page:

```
 gg <- df <- data.frame(gp = factor(rep(letters[1:3], each = 10)),
                  y = rnorm(30))

 library(plyr)
 ds <- ddply(df, .(gp), summarise, mean = mean(y), sd = sd(y))
 gg2 <-ggplot(df, aes(x = gp, y = y)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_point(data = ds, aes(y = mean),
               colour = 'red', size = 3)+theme(panel.border=element_rect(fill=NA) )
 grid.arrange(gg2,gg2, ncol=2)
```

Or perhaps this depending on your meeaning:

```
 gg2 <-ggplot(df, aes(x = gp, y = y)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_point(data = ds, aes(y = mean),
               colour = 'red', size = 3)+theme(plot.background = element_rect(size=3,linetype="solid",color="black"))
 grid.arrange(gg2,gg2, ncol=2)
```

If you just want a bordering rectangle:

```
grid.rect(.5,.5,width=unit(.99,"npc"), height=unit(0.99,"npc"), 
          gp=gpar(lwd=3, fill=NA, col="blue"))
```

Comment: the solution above does not draw the border/box around both the unrelated plots? i am looking for one box/border that encloses all the plots produced by grid.arrange. thanks

Comment: you might want to set `fill=NA` explicitly, as it may default to "white" on some devices, thereby covering the plots below.

Comment: Good point. That did occur to me on a machine that was running earlier version of R although not on 3.1.0 just now.