# How to add a border around a chart created via arrange.grid in gridExtra encompassing a set ggplot2 scatter plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, border, scatter-plot, gridextra

I'm using the code below:

```
# Libs
require(ggplot2); require(gridExtra); require(grid)

# Generate separate charts
chrts_list_scts <- list()

# Data
data("mtcars")

# A
chrts_list_scts$a <- ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(size = 2, aes(x = mpg, y = disp,
                           colour = as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = mpg, y = disp),
              method = "auto") +
  xlab("MPG") +
  ylab("Disp") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none")

# B
chrts_list_scts$b <- ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(size = 2, aes(x = mpg, y = drat,
                           colour = as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = mpg, y = drat),
              method = "auto") +
  xlab("MPG") +
  ylab("Drat") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none")

# C
chrts_list_scts$c <- ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(size = 2, aes(x = mpg, y = qsec,
                           colour = as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = mpg, y = qsec),
              method = "auto") +
  xlab("MPG") +
  ylab("QSEC") +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(title = "cyl")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.key = element_rect(colour = NA))

# Arrange grid
png(filename = "chrts.PNG", width = 6,
    height = 10, units = 'in', res = 300)
title_text <- c("mtcars")
chrts_list_scts$all_scts <- grid.arrange(chrts_list_scts$a,
                                         chrts_list_scts$b,
                                         chrts_list_scts$c,
                                         top =
                                           textGrob(label = title_text,
                                                    gp = gpar(
                                                      fontsize = 14,
                                                      font = 2)))
dev.off()
rm(title_text)
```

To generate the following chart:

[image: first chart]

**I'm interested in adding border around that chart,** as in the picture below:

[image: with border]

## Attempts

I tried to address this request via adding `polygonGrob` in the code:

```
chrts_list_scts$all_scts <- grid.arrange(chrts_list_scts$dep_work,
                                         chrts_list_scts$chld_work,
                                         chrts_list_scts$pens,
                                         polygonGrob(x = c(0,0.5,1.05),
                                                     y = c(0,0.5,1.05)
                                                     ),
                                         top =
                                           textGrob(label = title_text,
                                                    gp = gpar(
                                                      fontsize = 14,
                                                      font = 2)))
```

but this generates a pointless chart with one line across in the bottom. I had a look at the seeming similar [discussion on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25616788/how-to-draw-a-box-border-around-plots-arranged-side-by-side-using-grid-arrange-i) but it wasn't clear to me how to arrive at a working solution.

### Side requirements

In addition to generating the border, I would like to:

1. Be able to exercise some control over the border aesthetics, like changing size and colour of the border.
2. Ideally, I would like to encapsulate this solution *within* the `arrange.grid` call. So at the object `chrts_list_scts$all_scts` has all elements including charts and neat border around all of them.

---

*I will be happy to accept solutions that address the major requirements with respect to the border only, if there is a suggested solution that matches the remaining two points it will be even nicer.*

Comment: Have you read [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25618284/1305688)?

Comment: @EricFail If I reckon correctly, I've linked this answer in my post. I came across it when looking for similar problems but it wasn't clear to me how to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: My bad (there's a limit to how short my comment can be, so here's s some fill text to work around that annoying limitation)

Comment: @EricFail No problem at all, thank you for showing the interest in my modest problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**1)** Using the iris example (but further simplified) from the link provided in the question just add the last line.  Modify the `gpar(...)` components (and possibly the `width` and `height`) to get different aesthetics.  (This is not encapsulated in the `grid.arrange` call.)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

g <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) + geom_point()
grid.arrange(g, g, ncol=2)


# next line adds border
grid.rect(width = .98, height = .98, gp = gpar(lwd = 2, col = "blue", fill = NA))
```

(continued after plot)

[image: screenshot]

**2)** This is a variation of solution (1) in which on the plus side encapsulates both the graphics and border in the `gt` gTree by creating grobs to hold each.  On the other hand it does involve some additional complexity:

```
grid.newpage()
ga <- arrangeGrob(g, g, ncol = 2)
gb <- rectGrob(height = .98, width = .98, gp = gpar(lwd = 2, col = "blue", fill = NA)) # border, no fill
gt <- gTree(children = gList(ga, gb))
grid.draw(gt)
```

Comment: added encapsulated solution at end

Comment: Thanks very much for the excellent solution. At some point I added `fill = NA` to the statement `grid.rect(width = .98, height = 1, gp = gpar(lwd = 1, col = "black", fill = NA))` as once I got a white square covering the charts (after adding the `grid.rect` line after the chart definition.

Answer (score 2):

you can add a rectGrob to the gtable

```
grid.draw(gtable::gtable_add_grob(arrangeGrob(g, g, ncol=2),
             rectGrob(gp=gpar(lwd=5, fill=NA)), 1, 1, 1, 2))
```

NOTE: `fill=NA` or `fill='transparent'` is required otherwise the rectangle can mask the objects below it.